# How to assign a 3d numpy array using 2d coordinates efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3d numpy array representing an RGB image with a shape of (512, 512, 3).
I also have a list of coordinates representing pixels in a particular order that I then rotate a certain number of places. The coords array is static and is generated once throughout the program.
I want to create a new numpy array with the corresponding transformation in the pixel list.

The current code I'm currently using looks like this:

```py
import numpy as np

coords: [(int, int)] = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (3,3)] # for example

def rotate_coords(im1: np.array, n: int) -> np.array:
    im2 = np.copy(im1)
    for destination_coord, source_coord in zip(coords[-n:] + coords[:-n], coords):
        im2[destination_coord] = im1[source_coord ]
    return im2
```

Is there anyway to speed it up, perhaps by assigning every coordinate all at once?

Comment: I tried to use Numpy's [`roll`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html#numpy-roll) function to roll the "coords" list elements in a cyclic manner and then index the selected elements of your RGB array and update it accordingly. But the speed is similar if not worse than that of your algorithm, even for large RGB arrays or large coords list.